# What is the alternative of PL/Java for PostgreSQL 11 and 12?

Tags: postgresql, functions, postgresql-12, windows-10

Understand from: https://www.enterprisedb.com/edb-docs/d/edb-postgres-advanced-server/user-guides/user-guide/11/EDB_Postgres_Advanced_Server_Guide.1.80.html

that PL/Java is deprecated in Advanced Server 11 and will be unavailable in server versions 12 or later.

May I know:

1. What is the recommended replacement for PL/Java in PostgreSQL12?
2. For my existing UDF in PostgreSQL 9.6.x, etc., which is using the PL/Java, how could I move over to PostgreSQL 12?

If PostgreSQL is not going to have support for PL/Java in the future, please advise too.

Comment: You are looking at the documentation for a commercial Postgres distribution, while referring to Postgres in the question; which one is it? While EDB may discontinute support for Java, you can always [grab the  extension](https://tada.github.io/pljava/) yourself.

Comment: Hi, and welcome to dba.se! You could look [here](https://tada.github.io/pljava/)...

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I have the jar and DLL for a 9.6.x PostgreSQL, which failed to work when running the installation SQL of the PL/Java on PostgreSQL12. I was also not able to find any later version of PL/Java for PostgreSQL12 on windows machine (even from ur link), and with the notice that I saw, I could only conclude that it is no longer available from PostgreSQL 11 and 12 onwards. Is my understanding wrong?